# Swift Keyboard hides Textviews Text

Tags: swift, keyboard, textview

In my app i have a textview that that takes up the whole screen, only problem is when editing the keyboard will hide the text under the keyboard

There is no fancy code or anything just a textview

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKbmR.png)

Comment: You've said yourself that your textview takes up the entire screen.  So what seems to be the problem?  Are you saying you don't want to show the virtual keyboard?

Comment: no when the user closes the keyboard it should show them there note on the full screen not on a small square that wouldn't make sense apps like evernote the keyboard won't cover the text your writing

Answer (score 0):

1. make your view controller a UITextFieldDelegate
2. add this method which called after each keystroke

   textField:textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString
3. You would then add code so your textfield view is not hiding behind the keyboard, such as if textField.text! is so long move view up x this amount.